# How do I run local GAE emulator with Go 1.12?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

With Go 1.9 you ran a local GAE emulator with "dev_appserver.py yaml"

It seems google-cloud-sdk/ is deprecated.

The Go 1.12 documentation says you can run an emulator locally with "go run"
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/testing-and-deploying-your-app

I was not able to run the demo app at with:
google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld

$ go run *.go

```
2019/09/25 10:57:27 INFO: Serving the front page.
panic: Metadata fetch failed for 'instance/attributes/gae_project': Get http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/gae_project: dial tcp: lookup metadata: no such host

goroutine 5 [running]:
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.mustGetMetadata(0x1474a38, 0x1f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/metadata.go:34 +0x18a
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.partitionlessAppID(0x0, 0xc0000304c0)
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/identity_vm.go:112 +0xa2
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.DefaultTicket.func1()
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:294 +0x86
sync.(*Once).Do(0x17f0150, 0x1484448)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xb3
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.DefaultTicket(0xc0001945d0, 0x13b78e0)
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:289 +0x39
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.Call(0x14d9f00, 0xc0001945d0, 0x146a718, 0xa, 0x14666df, 0x5, 0x14d8ec0, 0xc0000304c0, 0x14d80c0, 0xc00000c1e0, ...)
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:496 +0x8ea
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.(*context).flushLog(0xc0001920c0, 0x1484b01, 0xc00002e100)
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:641 +0x3c7
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.handleHTTP.func1(0xc00002e120, 0xc0001920c0)
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:138 +0x56
created by google.golang.org/appengine/internal.handleHTTP
    /Users/Steve/go/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:134 +0x350
exit status 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that there isn't an emulator for App Engine from Go 1.12 onward. You run your project as a regular Go program because, for the most part, now it *is* just a regular Go program.

That `helloworld` example hasn't been updated to follow the new conventions for Go 1.12 on App Engine... notably because it resides WITHIN the old deprecated libraries. You no longer call `appengine.Main`, just `http.ListenAndServe` as you'd do normally outside App Engine.

They've come (mostly) full circle and opened it up so that the standard library calls that you would use in a normal Go program are now what you use on App Engine, with a few exceptions. This makes it easy to push almost any existing standalone Go program to App Engine with much less friction, which is a win for them and a win for developers.

Even if you are starting fresh and not migrating from the legacy SDK you should give this article a read, as it outlines a number of changes that you'll want to be aware of and watch out for in open source libs that could possibly still be legacy. If you are migrating it will be especially useful.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/go-differences

Notable snippet:

> App Engine no longer modifies the Go toolchain to include the appengine package. If you are using the appengine package or the google.golang.org/appengine package, you must migrate to the Google Cloud client library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is late, but I was using dev_appserver.py bla,bla,bla but after an `gcloud components update`, the script stoped working, but still you can use:

```
go run .
```